# Required property from React hook form does not validate on textfields

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-hook-form

I'm currently using React-hook-form to manage my textfields and that includes validation.
The problem right now is that the required property does not work well, because it does not show the little helpertext under the inputfield when it is empty.
Here is there a snippet of the UI, it only shows a few of the inputfields to save you the
unnecessary JSX code
[image]

This is how i have done it:

```
import { FragmentType, useFragment } from '@gql/fragment-masking';
import { graphql } from '@gql/gql';
import { Gender } from '@gql/graphql';
import {
  Button,
  Card,
  CardContent,
  Grid,
  MenuItem,
  TextField,
  TextFieldProps,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { DesktopDatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import dayjs, { Dayjs } from 'dayjs';
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

type Inputs = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  birthdate: string;
  street: string;
  postalcode: string;
  city: string;
  country: string;
  gender: string;
  email: string;
  leveloftrust: string;
  lastsignedin: string;
};

export const PatientInfoFragment = graphql(/* GraphQL */ `
  fragment PatientInfo on Patient {
    addresses {
      city
      lines
      postalCode
    }
    birthDate
    email
    gender
    id
    name {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
    status {
      lastSignInAt
      levelOfTrust
    }
  }
`);

interface PatientInfoProps {
  patient: FragmentType<typeof PatientInfoFragment>;
}

export function PatientInfo(props: PatientInfoProps) {
  const patient = useFragment(PatientInfoFragment, props.patient);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Dayjs | null>(
    dayjs(patient.birthDate)
  );
  const genderValueArray = Object.values(Gender);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<Inputs>({
    defaultValues: {
      firstName: patient.name?.firstName ?? '',
      lastName: patient.name?.lastName ?? '',
      birthdate: patient.birthDate ?? '',
      country: '',
      gender: patient.gender,
      email: patient.email ?? '',
      leveloftrust: patient.status?.levelOfTrust,
      lastsignedin: patient.status?.lastSignInAt,
      postalcode: patient.addresses[0]?.postalCode ?? '',
      city: patient.addresses[0]?.city ?? '',
      street: patient.addresses[0]?.lines[0] ?? '',
    },
    shouldUseNativeValidation: true,
  });

  const handleChange = React.useCallback(
    (newValue: Dayjs | null) => setValue(newValue),
    []
  );

  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const handleEditClick = useCallback(() => setDisabled(!disabled), [disabled]);

  const renderInputField = React.useCallback(
    (params: JSX.IntrinsicAttributes & TextFieldProps) => {
      return <TextField {...params} />;
    },
    []
  );

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => console.log(data);

  return (
    <Card>
      <CardContent>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Grid container direction="row" justifyContent="space-between">
            <Grid item>
              <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
                {t('patient.info.title', 'Personal Information')}
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Grid container justifyContent="space-between" sx={{ m: 1 }}>
                {!disabled && (
                  <Button
                    onClick={handleEditClick}
                    size="large"
                    variant="outlined">
                    Cancel
                  </Button>
                )}
                <Button
                  onClick={handleEditClick}
                  size="large"
                  type="submit"
                  variant="contained">
                  {!disabled
                    ? t('patient.setToComplete', 'Set to complete')
                    : t('patient.edit', 'Edit')}
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container direction="row">
            <Grid
              container
              sx={{ margin: 1 }}
              rowSpacing={3}
              spacing={{ md: 4 }}>
              <Grid item>
                <TextField
                  {...register('firstName', { required: 'Field needs to be filled out' })}
                  label="Name"
                  name="firstName"
                  id="component-outlined"
                  disabled={disabled}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <TextField
                  {...register('lastName', {
                    required: 'Field needs to be filled out',
                  })}
                  label="lastname"
                  name="lastName"
                  id="component-outlined"
                  disabled={disabled}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item sx={{ width: '274.67px' }}>
                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                  <DesktopDatePicker
                    {...register('birthdate', {
                      required: 'Field needs to be filled out',
                    })}
                    label="Birthdate"
                    inputFormat="MM/DD/YYYY"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    renderInput={renderInputField}
                    disabled={disabled}
                  />
                </LocalizationProvider>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              container
              sx={{ margin: 1 }}
              rowSpacing={3}
              spacing={{ md: 4 }}>
              <Grid item>
                <TextField
                  {...register('street')}
                  id="component-outlined"
                  label="Street"
                  name="street"
                  disabled={disabled}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <TextField
                  {...register('postalcode')}
                  id="component-outlined"
                  label="Postal code"
                  name="postalCode"
                  disabled={disabled}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <TextField
                  {...register('city')}
                  id="component-outlined"
                  label="City"
                  name="city"
                  disabled={disabled}
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              container
              sx={{ margin: 1 }}
              rowSpacing={3}
              spacing={{ md: 4 }}>
              <Grid item>
                <TextField
                  {...register('country')}
                  id="component-outlined"
                  label="Country"
                  name="country"
                  disabled={disabled}
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <TextField
                  sx={{ width: '242.67px' }}
                  id="outlined-select-gender"
                  select
                  {...register('gender')}
                  label="Gender"
                  disabled={disabled}
                  value={patient.gender}>
                  {genderValueArray.map(option => (
                    <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
                      {option}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
                </TextField>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <TextField
                  {...register('email')}
                  id="component-outlined"
                  label="Email"
                  name="email"
                  disabled
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid
              container
              sx={{ margin: 1 }}
              rowSpacing={3}
              spacing={{ md: 4 }}>
              <Grid item>
                <TextField
                  {...register('leveloftrust')}
                  id="component-outlined"
                  label="Level of trust"
                  name="leveloftrust"
                  disabled
                />
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>
                <TextField
                  {...register('lastsignedin')}
                  id="component-outlined"
                  label="Last signed in"
                  name="lastsignedin"
                  disabled
                />
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `React Hook Form` with `MUI` `Textfield`, you'll need to use the `Controller` component wrapper from `react-hook-form` for your MUI Textfield components.

View [Integrating with UI Libraries](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries)

For example, you would grab the `Input` component from MUI's `Core` library instead:

```
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
```

Then in your form you'd wrap it using `Controller` like:

```
<Controller
  name="firstName"
  control={control}
  render={({ field }) => <Input {...field} />}
/>
```

Then MUI `Input` has has `error` `boolean` and `helperText` `string` as available properties on the `Input` component. For example using `Formik` (but any form library would work with MUI):

```
<TextField
  id="password"
  name="password"
  label="Password"
  type="password"
  value={formik.values.password}
  onChange={formik.handleChange}
  error={!!formik.errors.password && formik.touched.password}
  helperText={formik.touched.password && formik.errors.password}
  required
/>
```

Otherwise, reviewing their documentation on how to [Handle Errors](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Handleerrors), it appears with no library they have you handle error output manually using the `errors` object from `formState`. You'd destructure that data like:

```
const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
```

Finally, they link a [very handy CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-errormessage-multiple-error-messages-3ur2z?file=/src/index.js) which uses a `@hookform/error-message` library that can wrap regular HTML inputs. If you want to stick with MUI, I'd go with the `helperText` and `error` properties.